# Generating dependency diagram with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

How to generate a Maven dependency diagram with IntelliJ that will show the dependencies, both parent, modules, and dependencies with *com.mycompany* package. Meaning, *parents*, *modules*, and *dependencies* that are not under com.mycompany will not be shown.

The context menu, "Maven Show Dependencies" apparently cannot achieve this?

Additionally, the IntelliJ Maven Diagram plugin can't display dependencies under `<dependencyManagement>`

Comment: I believe that is only supported out of the box with the Ultimate edition.  https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html

Comment: Yes I am using IntelliJ Ultimate edition but the maven dependency diagram is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use: https://github.com/ferstl/depgraph-maven-plugin

Then run

`mvn depgraph:aggregate -DgraphFormat=gml`

This will generate the Maven dependency graph.